# What's the meaning about " is_answered" field of question object?

Tags: support, api, questions

I saw the [question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question) object has a `is_answered` field.

I mentioned that there're the following cases:

1. The `is_answered` field is true, and the question has an accepted answer.
2. The `is_answered` field is true, and the question has an unaccepted answer
3. The `is_answered` field is false, and the question has an unaccepted answer.
4. The `is_answered` field is false, and the question has no answer.

I'm confused about this field, what actually does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to report a bug?  If so, provide specific examples, with question ID's.

---

The `is_answered` property is true when the question owner has selected one of the answers as "accepted". See [*Help Center > Answering*](https://stackapps.com/help/accepted-answer) on any site:

> When a user receives a good answer to their question, that user has the option to "accept" an answer. Acceptance is indicated by a colored checkmark next to the answer that has been accepted by the original author of the question.
>
> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. **It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for them personally. Not every user comes back to accept an answer**<sup>‡</sup>...

This is consistent with your 4 cases. Refer to this Venn diagram:

[image: Venn D]

Only questions in the green circle will have `is_answered` set to true.

So of your 4 cases:

1. is_answered is **true**, and  question has an **accepted answer**.
   -- That's the **green circle**.
2. is_answered is **true**, and  question **has an unaccepted answer**.
   -- That's questions that are in the **intersection of the purple circle and the green circle**.
3. is_answered is **false**, and question **has an unaccepted answer**.
   -- That's questions that are **in the blue circle and outside the green circle**.
4. is_answered is **false**, and **question has no answer**.
   -- That's questions that are **in the black circle and outside the blue circle**.

---

<sup>‡</sup> "But anybody who has a *shred* of human decency does"...

Comment: So, how can I detect if the question has an accepted answer? Using the `is_answered` field seems not correct.

Comment: No, the `is_answered` field is *exactly* the right way to tell if a question has an accepted answer.  Use `accepted_answer_id` to get the post id of that answer.